# What are some examples of Build.PRODUCT in Android

Tags: android, android-tv, television

What are some examples of Build.PRODUCT in Android? I am looking for a way to the operator name on android tv set top boxes, the most probable value I think is Build.PRODUCT but I need to see some examples of the values it can take. If you don't have this information, can you point me to where I can get it from?

Comment: Did you ever find anything?

Comment: Operator name is Build.BRAND, Build.PRODUCT the name given to this device by the operator.